# How to get address from Google Sheets if I had position of row and column?

Tags: python, google-sheets

.Hello, everyone. I need some help.

I'm trying to put data into my Google Sheet via this:

```
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Everyday!B131", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":time_value}).execute()
```

But instead the cell with address B131, I need to put data another cell with unknown address. But I know what is the row and column.
How can I get the address in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the column and row, then you should be able to concatenate them into the address:

```
column = '131'
row = 'B'
sheet = 'Everyday'

address = sheet + '!' + row + column
print(address)
```

```
output: Everyday!B131
```

Comment: Thank you and I'm sorry, but it's now working. I need address with quotes. But when I write like this:
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=address_format, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":time_value}).execute()
with quotes it sends me the message: 
HttpError
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting ...=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: "Everyday!B131"". Details: "Unable to parse range: "Everyday!B131"">

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but if what you mean is that you need your address string variable to include quotes, you should just be able to include them in the variable itself. Concatenate them with the rest of the address (use single quotes since you are including double quotes as part of the string).

Comment: I have concatenated them, but I don't know it's not worked. I will try to solve the problem. I wrote like this: address_format = '"{}"'.format(address) and also like this: address_format = "'{}'".format(address)

Comment: Martig G, I did this! Oh my, god, I just writing and writing different variants. And it's worked for me:
address = "Everyday" + "!" + str(current_col) + str(current_row)
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=address, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":time_value}).execute()

The problem was with variables current_row at the begining. It had a value 'None'. But I tryed use it with double quotes, single quotes. Haha. Thank you for your attention!)

Comment: Congratulations! I am glad you figured it out. :)